# Damping a spring force

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, friction, simulations, spring, numerical-method

I'm modelling particles in a system using a spring and damper force.

$$F= kx -cv$$

$x=x_i -x_f$, where $x_i$=centre of spring and $x_f$= displaced position.

Above $x$ is the displacement and $v$ is the velocity in the previous timestep. I don't want the particles to vibrate too much upon displacement, thus I increase $c$ to very high. But I notice they then start moving rapidly along the centre of displacement. Does this make sense or am going wrong somewhere when coding it?

Comment: Hi Abhishek, ignoring the damping for now, shouldn't it be F = -kx not F = kx?  That is, the force due to the spring should be in the opposite direction to the displacement.  If the spring is displaced to the right, the force should be to the left.

Comment: @Mew Thanks for the reply! $x=x_i -x_f$, where $x_i$=centre of spring and $x_f$= displaced position. So, it is actually the same. Sorry for mentioning that, I have added it. What you say makes much more sense, my physical notations are very bad.

Answer (score 4):

What matters here is how the value of $c$ compares to the value of $k$.

Let us choose a $\zeta = \frac{c}{2\sqrt{mk}}$

One can show that when $\zeta =1 $ the system is critically damped, and will not exhibited any oscillations and will return to the origin in the shortest possible time interval.

When $\zeta > 1 $ the system is over damped and will take longer than reach the equilibrium position, but will still not exhibit oscillatory motion.

When $\zeta < 1 $ the system will exhibit oscillatory motion at the natural frequency, and the amplitude will gradually decrease over time.

Therefore if you want the system to exhibit no oscillatory motion and move to the origin in the shortest time frame, choose $\zeta = \frac{c}{2\sqrt{mk}} = 1$and thus set $c = 2\sqrt{mk}$.

The diagram below shows the oscillatory behavior for various values of $\zeta$:

[image]

Comment: Great! Thanks for reply! Can you also explain why does it take the system longer than to reach the equilibrium position when it is over damped and what is $\zeta$ called, in this respect?

Comment: @AbhishekBhatia, this is because the friction is so high, not only does it not oscillate, the large friction will also cause the system to take a long time to simply return to the original position.  You can thus lower the friction to the critical value and it will still not oscillate but it will reach equilibrium quicker because there is less friction opposing the motion to the equilibrium position.

Comment: @AbhishekBhatia, the quantity is called damping ratio.

Comment: Thanks again! I am confused at following, consider a particle is displaced by $x$ along the positive x direction. Now, the friction exerts a huge force along the negative x direction due to very high $c$. Now, shouldn't the particle be displaced along the negative $x$ direction due to that force. This return causing an oscillation.

Comment: @AbhishekBhatia, the force of friction is always in the opposite direction to velocity.  The force of friction can therefore only act to slow down an object, it can't cause it to accelerate in the opposite direction.

Comment: This also may be likely an issue due not a sufficiently low time-step taken for simulation of the above scenario.

Comment: Thanks so much! It makes sense from your explanations, I have check my code again. Can you please also add a derivation of damping ratio's formula. It will help me understand it better.

Comment: @AbhishekBhatia, do you understand how to solve second order differential equations?